# ¿Como generar un menú dinámico con NavigationView que contenga un contador de notificaciones?

Tags: java, android, navigationview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android que contiene un menú que se genera dinámicamente, con lo que el menú lo genero por programación:

```
private void cargarAvisosMenu() 
{
    // Menu
    final Menu menu = this.mNavigationView.getMenu();


    // Carga de datos
    CentroSelection selection = new CentroSelection();
    CentroCursor cur = selection.query(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());

    // Recorro el cursor de centros
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        boolean avisosTipoA = false;
        boolean avisosTipoB = false;

        Centro c = Centro.getFromCursor(cur);
        if (c.getIsTipoAVisible() && c.getComponenteTipoA().getControlesTipoAPendientes() > 0) {
            avisosTipoA = true;
        }
        if (c.getIsTipoBVisible() && c.getComponenteTipoB().getControlesTipoBPendientes() > 0){
            avisosTipoB = true;
        }

        if (avisosTipoA || avisosTipoB) {
            // Añado la sección y los items.
            final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(c.getNombre());
            if (avisosTipoA) {
                subMenu.add("TipoA").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tipoA);
            }
            if (avisosTipoB) {
                subMenu.add("TipoB").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tipoB);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mi intención es agregar un contador que indique el número de notificaciones (al estilo de gmail).

Según la documentación esto es posible, bien a través de un menú xml, utilizando el atributo `app:actionLayout`, o bien utilizando la función `MenuItemCompat.setActionView()`. Puesto que el menú que estoy desarrollando es dinámico, he optado por la segunda opción, de modo que el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
private void cargarAvisosMenu() 
{
    // Menu
    final Menu menu = this.mNavigationView.getMenu();


    // Carga de datos
    CentroSelection selection = new CentroSelection();
    CentroCursor cur = selection.query(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());

    // Recorro el cursor de centros
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        boolean avisosTipoA = false;
        boolean avisosTipoB = false;

        Centro c = Centro.getFromCursor(cur);
        if (c.getIsTipoAVisible() && c.getComponenteTipoA().getControlesTipoAPendientes() > 0) {
            avisosTipoA = true;
        }
        if (c.getIsTipoBVisible() && c.getComponenteTipoB().getControlesTipoBPendientes() > 0){
            avisosTipoB = true;
        }

        if (avisosTipoA || avisosTipoB) {
            // Añado la sección y los items.
            final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(c.getNombre());
            if (avisosTipoA) {
                subMenu.add("TipoA").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tipoA);
            }
            if (avisosTipoB) {
                // subMenu.add("TipoB").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tipoB);
                int itemId = subMenu.add("TipoB").getItemId();
                View menuItem = MenuItemCompat.setActionView(subMenu.findItem(itemId), R.layout.menu_notificaciones).getActionView();
                ((ImageView) menuItem.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuNotificaciones)).setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_barcode));
                ((TextView) menuItem.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuNotificaciones)).setText("TipoB");
                ((TextView) menuItem.findViewById(R.id.tvContadorNotificaciones)).setText("100");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y el fichero "menu_notificaciones.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMenuNotificaciones"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMenuNotificaciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContadorNotificaciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Sin embargo el menú no carga la vista "menu_notificaciones".

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no carga la vista? Si vas paso por paso, ¿llegas a la linea `int itemId = subMenu.add("TipoB").getItemId();`?

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando ejecuto la aplicación, en el item de menu no carga la vista de "menu_notificaciones.xml", sino que carga el elemento de menu por defecto, es decir, como si solo ejecutara `subMenu.add("TipoB")`. Respecto a lo que me preguntas, sí, llego a esa línea y ejecuta las demás correctamente, sin embargo parece que no tiene ningún efecto sobre la aplicación.

Comment: ¿la respuesta resolvió el problema?

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y sigue sin funcionar. No se si lo estoy haciendo de forma incorrecta. ¿Podrías facilitarme algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finalmente he solucionado el problema creando el menú manualmente, introduciendo un `ListView` dentro del componente `NavigationView`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Contenido principal -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Menú Deslizable -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- Menú Deslizable basado en ListView -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Si no me equivoco, este es el modo que se utilizaba antiguamente para el desarrollo de los menús. Soy consciente de que no es la solución que buscaba, sin embargo no encuentro el modo de agregar el contador por código directamente al control `NavigationView`.

Answer (score 5):

De acuerdo con [`setActionView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(int)) la acción será reemplazada cuando este ítem se muestra como una acción dentro del padre.

Te falta indicar esta acción. Puedes hacer esto utilizando [`setShowAsAction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction(int)). Esto describe cuando este ítem puede ser mostrado.